# React Native: Recording crash on few android mobiles due to exo player used for react-native-video

Tags: android, react-native, performance

I hope you all are doing well.
I am using React Native : 0.64
react-native-video: 5.2.0
react-native-vision-camera for recording: 2.13.0

I am getting crash on few android mobiles , after i added exo player for react-native-video
Although it is working fine on IOS.

I am looking for any help , I am running with same issue since one month, i tried every trick on it but not reached to any solution , Please help

I tried to upgrade the version of React-native-video , but it didn't work, and i can't upgrade or downgrade the version of react-native-vision camera, it gives us error.

I am expecting that seniors would help me resolve the issue
Error log are in the below image
[Error log open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JoNr.png)

Comment: Share the error snippet? Be easier to debug if we could see the error log.

Comment: Thank you for reply, We are only getting log on android studio, let me share

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JoNr.png this is the link error log, looking forward